# Find all category, subcategory and sub sub category using Beautifuloup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the **category**, **sub category** and **sub sub category** and so on of authors URL from dmoz website using BeautifulSoup.

I'm getting the following output:

```
# Missing the every 2nd option/URL in first step
/Arts/Literature/Authors/A
/Arts/Literature/Authors/C
/Arts/Literature/Authors/E
/Arts/Literature/Authors/G
/Arts/Literature/Authors/Horror
. . .
# Missing the every 1st option/URL in second step
/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abbey,_Lynn
/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abe,_Kobo
```

In the above code 2nd element is missing in 1st step and 1st element in 2nd step.

Here is my code:

```
scrape_url = "http://dmoz.org/Arts/Literature/Authors"
page = session.get(scrape_url, headers={
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
})
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
find_row = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'row'})[6:7]

# get all the root category author list
for test in find_row:
    if test.find('div', attrs = {'class':'panel-body'}):
        test_link = test.find_all('a')
        for link in test_link:
            sub_cat.append(link['href'])

# now get the sub or sub-sub category author URL list
for cat in sub_cat:
    scrape_cat_url = "http://dmoz.org%s" % (cat)
    print('scraping...', scrape_cat_url)
    page = session.get(scrape_cat_url, headers={
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
    })
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')

    find_row = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'row'})[6:7]
    # if sub category go next level or restart
    for row in find_row:
        if row.find('div', attrs = {'class':'panel-body'}):
            test_link = row.find_all('a')
            for link in test_link:
                sub_cat.append(link['href'])
            records.append(scrape_cat_url)
        
        else:
            records.append(scrape_cat_url)
    # remove the category url from the sub_cat list
    sub_cat.remove(cat)
```

Can anybody suggest a better way to get all the category, sub category and sub sub category URL of authors?

Answer (score 1):

Try this streamlined version of your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}

scrape_url = "http://dmozlive.com/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors"
page = requests.get(scrape_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
find_rows = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'row'})[6:7]

cats = []

for row in find_rows:
    links = row.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        cats.append(link['href'])

cats
```

Print out:

```
['/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/B',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/C',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/D',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/E',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/F',
 …
```

Now get the subcategories:

```
sub_cats = []

for cat in cats:
    scrape_url = f"http://dmozlive.com{cat}"
    page = requests.get(scrape_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    find_rows = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'row'})[6:7]
    
    for row in find_rows:
        links = row.find_all('a')
        for link in links:
            sub_cats.append(link['href'])

subcats
```

Print out:

```
['/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abbey,_Edward',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abbey,_Lynn',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abbott,_Edwin_A.',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Abe,_Kobo',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Achebe,_Chinua',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Ackroyd,_Peter',
 '/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors/A/Adams,_Douglas',
 …
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @petezurich. The  streamlined of your code will scrape the main category then sub category only but if the sub category has sub sub category and go on, will this streamlined code work? Please have a look again. Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code may meet your expectation that's pull all the categories and sub-categories urls.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= 'http://dmozlive.com/Top/Arts/Literature/Authors'
headers= {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
req=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

for cat_url in soup.select('.list-group.col-md-6 a'):
    cat_url = 'http://dmozlive.com' + cat_url.get('href')
    #print(cat_url)
    req2=requests.get(cat_url,headers=headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.text, 'html.parser')
    for author_url in soup2.select('.list-group-item'):
        author_url= 'http://dmozlive.com' + str(author_url.get('href'))
        print(author_url)
```

Comment: Thanks @F.Hoque brother. I've tested your code and it scrape only sub category url but I need the main category then sub category again sub sub category and so on. If you have any suggestion that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Mehady, uncomment the` cat_url` that's the categories urls and to get sub sub categories go ahead for 3rd requests